# RSA key pair generated in iOS not supported in Android side

Tags: android, ios, rsa, android-support-library

Data successfully encrypted in Android with RSA public key(generated in iOS) but while decrypting with the help of RSA private key (generated in iOS) gives invalid key Exceptions. Please suggest

Comment: As is stands your question is unclear and incomplete for several reasons. Show the code that isn't working. Show the full stacktrace or error log that occurs when you run the code. Also, show some sample data that triggers the problem. With crypt, you don't want to reveal private keys yet the format of these may be the source of the problem, so instead show throwaway keys that are use only for testing and not operationally.